# No payment methods display for free products with shipping costs

Tags: magento, payment

We are creating a Magento store with many educational products. Many products are free booklets, but there are shipping costs for the order.

If I create an order with only free products and go through checkout, no payment methods will display and I can't complete the order.

How do I get the payment methods to show?

Some additional information:

- If I add a paid product to my cart, the payment methods will display.
- Some products are completely free (no shipping either). We gave them a weight of zero. If you only order those, it does work like it should. (No payment required.)
- There is only one shipping method available: Table Rates

Comment: Which payment methods are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue myself. Here's how:

First, make a local copy of the file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Form/Container.php (Copy the file to: app/code/**local**/Mage/Payment/Block/Form/Container.php)

Then go to line 119 and change:

```
$total = $quote->getBaseSubtotal();
```

to

```
$total = $quote->getBaseGrandTotal();
```

I've tested the change by placing an order of free products and finishing the order in the back-end. It all seems to work properly.

Comment: While this isn't the most elegant fix. I would suggest overriding this in a module, it does work. Nice post.

Comment: do you any idea for version 1.9.2